# Beamer serif fonttheme xelatex

Tags: beamer, xetex

Why doesn't serif fonts work when using beamer with xelatex and fontspec? (I my case!)

When I use standard LaTeX fonts with pdflatex I get the desired result: a presentation with serif fonts only (mwe 1)

When I use xelatex (fontspec, Minion Pro font, danish) I get titles and some parts serif, most of the text ends up as sans serif?

**Two minimal examples:**
1. compile with pdflatex
Two minimal examples:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[red]{Verona}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\title{Test af Serif}
\subtitle{sammen med Verona}
\author{Soeren Christensen}
\institute{Oerum sogn}
\date{1. januar 2018}

%\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

%\section*{Program}
%\begin{frame}
%  \frametitle{Program}
%  \tableofcontents%[pausesections]
%\end{frame}

\section{Rammen}

\begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Titel paa slide}
        \framesubtitle{undertitel}

        \begin{quotation}[Joh 3,16]
            For saaledes elskede Gud verden, at han gav sin enbaarne
            soen, for at enhver, der tror paa ham, ikke skal fortabes
            med have evigt liv.
        \end{quotation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**example 2 (compile with xelatex):**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}

\usetheme[red]{Verona}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Numbers=Lowercase]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Numbers=Lowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Menlo}

\title{Test af Serif}
\subtitle{sammen med Verona}
\author{Soeren Christensen}
\institute{Oerum sogn}
\date{1. januar 2018}

%\mode<presentation>

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Rammen}

\begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Titel paa slide}
        \framesubtitle{undertitel}

        \begin{quotation}[Joh 3,16]
            For saaledes elskede Gud verden, at han gav sin enbaarne
            soen, for at enhver, der tror paa ham, ikke skal fortabes
            med have evigt liv.
        \end{quotation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force beamer to use serif fonts with `\AtBeginDocument{\rmfamily}`.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{danish}

\usetheme[red]{Verona}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase,Mapping=tex-text}
\setromanfont[Numbers=Lowercase]{Minion Pro}
\setsansfont[Numbers=Lowercase]{Myriad Pro}
\setmonofont{Menlo}


\title{Test af Serif}
\subtitle{sammen med Verona}
\author{Soeren Christensen}
\institute{Oerum sogn}
\date{1. januar 2018}

%\mode<presentation>

\AtBeginDocument{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Rammen}

\begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Titel paa slide}
        \framesubtitle{undertitel}

        \begin{quotation}[Joh 3,16]
            For saaledes elskede Gud verden, at han gav sin enbaarne
            soen, for at enhver, der tror paa ham, ikke skal fortabes
            med have evigt liv.
        \end{quotation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]